# Does IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation support validating tokens from multiple authorities?

Tags: identityserver4

Does IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation support authentication of multiple authorities?

Normally, I setup the trust for my own single authority like so:

```
 .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ApiName = "TestApi";
            });
```

I need to auth tokens from my own authority as well as one other trusted external authority.  Not sure how to do it.

Comment: Do you mean from multiple custom Identity Servers or multiple sources such as Google, Facebook, Auth0 etc.?

Comment: Multiple identity servers.

Comment: I think he means two separate identity servers, one has users in localdb, the other with ldap, for example.  But service accept token from both and consider all request IsAuthenticated.  I'm looking for answers too.  Anyone?